# deploying a war-project with maven-phase execution

Tags: jakarta-ee, maven, tomcat, maven-plugin, liquibase

I specified a plugin (in the pom.xml) with an execution that should be execute in the process-resources phase. So once I start the project, it executes the goal(a change in the database with liquibase) before it compiles and runs the project.

```
<plugin>
  [...] 
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <phase>process-resources</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>update</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

When I deploy the project in the production, I have an war-package that gets deployed by tomcat.

But I'm not sure when and if the goal is executed. I want the goal to be executed just one time, once it gets deployed and before the application can be used by user.

How is the workflow in this case? Does the goal get automatically executed just once, or do I miss something here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 . "But I'm not sure when and if the goal is executed."

You can check the output of maven. Since you bind your goal to "process-resources" phase, you can check for "resources:resources" such as following:

```
   [INFO] [resources:resources {execution: yourExecutionId}]
```

It's a good practice to add id for each exection:

```
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>yourExecutionId</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
```

For more detail on maven build lifecycle, you can reference [here](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Lifecycle_Reference).

2 . "Does the goal get automatically executed just once, or do I miss something here."

Not always. Maven plugin can fork lifecycle which means  some phases will executed multiple times, e.g. [maven-source-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-source-plugin/).